# How generic method in java interface convert super object to concrete subclass object?

Tags: java, generics, interface, polymorphism

I have the following snippet, and it works fine.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App app = new App();
        app.setHandler(Apple.class, new AppleHandler());
        app.setHandler(Banana.class, new BananaHandler());

        app.process(new Apple());
        app.process(new Banana());
    }
}

class Fruit {}
class Apple extends Fruit {}
class Banana extends Fruit {}

interface Handler<T extends Fruit> {
    public void handle(T fruit);
}

class AppleHandler implements Handler<Apple> {
    @Override
    public void handle(final Apple fruit) {
        System.out.println("This is an apple.");
    }
}

class BananaHandler implements Handler<Banana> {
    @Override
    public void handle(final Banana fruit) {
        System.out.println("This is a banana.");
    }
}

class App {
    Map<Class, Handler> handlerMap = new HashMap<>();

    public void setHandler(Class clazz, Handler handler) {
        handlerMap.put(clazz, handler);
    }

    public void process(Fruit fruit) {
        Handler handler = handlerMap.get(fruit.getClass());
        handler.handle(fruit);// HERE, how java convert Fruit object to concrete subclass object automatically?
    }
}
```

I want `App` class to handle different `Fruit` in different ways, so I define `AppleHandler` to handle `Apple` and `BananaHandler` to handle `Banana`. Both `AppleHandler` and `BananaHandler` implements a generic interface `Handler` which has a generic method `handle`. `handle` method is given a `Fruit` object in `App.process` method, and concrete `handle` method will be invoked as expected. It seems that java casts a `Fruit` object to its real type automatically when invoke concrete `handle` method. How does java achieve this?

Comment: You question is: How does Java implement Polymorphism?

Comment: @DavidChoweller, NO. My question is: How does java convert Fruit object to Apple or Banana object when invoke concrete handle method (this is called polymorphism)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems that java casts a Fruit object to its real type automatically when invoke concrete handle method. How does java achieve this?

This is correct. The compiler inserts a cast based on the generic parameter. This is tricky to see in your code, since you use so many raw types.

When you do:

```
Handler handler = handlerMap.get(fruit.getClass());
handler.handle(fruit);
```

The generic parameter of `handler` is not known, so `fruit` is passed to the erased form of the `handle` method, which looks something like:

```
public void handle(Fruit fruit)
```

So the code compiles. But at that point, dynamic dispatch kicks in an calls the overridden implementation of `handle` which is for instance the one you defined in `AppleHandler`:

```
@Override
public void handle(final Apple fruit) {
    System.out.println("This is an apple.");
}
```

At that point the generic parameter *is* known and the argument is cast to `Apple`.

This cast can also be seen in the bytecode of the `AppleHandler` class:

```
 public void handle(test.Fruit);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: aload_1
       2: checkcast     #35                 // class test/Apple
       5: invokevirtual #37                 // Method handle:(Ltest/Apple;)V
       8: return
```

Answer (score 0):

The code works because you are exploiting raw types by using `Handler` in your `Map`.

By using raw types you have something like `Map<Class<Object>, Handler<Object>>`, so any kind of object can be used to retrieve the correct `Handler<Object>`. The fact that code works is merely given by the fact that mappers are correctly setup. Nothing prevents you from doing

```
app.setHandler(Apple.class, new BananaHandler());
app.setHandler(Banana.class, new AppleHandler());
```

which yields a `ClassCastException`:

```
tests.Main$Apple cannot be cast to tests.Main$Banana
```

So there's not black magic here, just try to use generic type variables and you'll see that the same code won't work without coercing the type of the `Handler`.

Because of type erasure your `AppleHandler` implementation is compiled as

```
class AppleHandler {
  void handle(Object object) {
    Apple apple = (Apple)object;
    System.out.println("This is an apple");
  }
}
```

so from outside no casts are required to dispatch the fruit to the correct handler but this also implies that there's no way for the compiler to ensure that dispatch will be correct at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void process(Fruit fruit) {
    Handler handler = handlerMap.get(fruit.getClass());
```

Right here, the parameter is a `Fruit`, but the actual class is `Banana`. So when you say fruit.getClass() that's returning `Banana`, so it's getting the `Banana` handler

Comment: Yeah, you are right. But, Banana.handle was given a Fruit object, how and when was it casted to a Banana object?

Comment: @expoter no you are confused. process was given a Banana. Banana is a subclass of Fruit, so when the process method is called, the fruit object is actually a Banana, not a Fruit which is the polymorphism going on. There's no conversion happening.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you get rid of the `Handler` interface, and put the `handle()` method in `Fruit/Apple/...`  would make the example better.

In java, we access an object (say, type `T`) via a reference variable, this is the only way. Once the ref variable is created to an object (T or subTypes of T), the type of the reference variable cannot be changed, it can be reassigned to other variable. The type of the reference variable will determine the methods that it can invoke on the object.

You create an object with `new Apple()`, a ref-var was declared to the **Apple** object,  No matter it is `Fruit a = new Apple()` or `Apple a = new apple()`  both a refer to an object of `Apple`, Even later you do `Object o = a;`, the `o` refers to the `Apple` object too.  So if you do `Fruit a = new Apple(); a.doSomething()`, java will find the `Apple` object, and execute the `doSomething()` method of `Apple` class/object.

Comment: Thanks for your advice!